# how to change style of notifier angular and add an icon in it

Tags: angular, angular7, notificationservices

I use angular-notifier package in my angular 7 project. I added its selector in app.component.html before router-outlet.
I add its config in app.module.ts in imports.
I can not chane some style in it. for example add an icon, or change \n to next line, etc

Comment: Can you point us towards the library?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-notifier

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use mdbootsatap package

```
 <div class="toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
          <div class="toast-header">
            <svg class=" rounded mr-2" width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
              focusable="false" role="img">
              <rect fill="#007aff" width="100%" height="100%" /></svg>
            <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
            <small class="text-muted">11 mins ago</small>
            <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="toast-body">
            Hello, world! This is a toast message.
          </div>
        </div>
```